# How can parents prevent middle child syndrome?

Tags: parents, siblings

A child can develop [Middle Child Syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middle_child_syndrome) when feeling left out by the family. It can easily be caused by parents being too involved with the older and younger siblings and not making enough time with the middle one.

What are the extra challenges that parents can face with the middle child and how to overcome them?

Answer (score 4):

The best way that I can think of is to schedule time with all of your kids.  Basically, you have certain days of the week (or hours) where you will spend with your middle child and work only on his/her interests.  If any of the kids complain, I recommend to sit them down and explain that you love them all and each one should equal time (assuming they are old enough.)

Or, if they are too young, find a common activity that everyone can enjoy.

Comment: We try to schedule one-on-one days with our kids.  One Saturday a month one child gets an entire "day with Mommy" and once a week a child gets a "day with Daddy".  Since we only have two, we can do mommy day and daddy day at the same time, but you could stagger the schedule.  They get to pick where we go to lunch, and they can pick a particular fun activity to do with the parent of the day.  If you put the schedule on the calendar that makes it official, and they know that they are at least as important as a doctor's appointment :)